# grpc::AsyncGenericService giving segmentation fault on RequestCall method?

Tags: c++, grpc

The program(C++) I am working on is for Service proxy. It is using `AsyncGenericService` of grpc in its implementation. The program is crashing(segmentation fault) just after calling the [RequestCall()](https://grpc.github.io/grpc/cpp/classgrpc_1_1_async_generic_service.html#a6e80755bf20d17baafcfb65c6a144c00) method.

Some pieces of code lines are follows:

```
::grpc::AsyncGenericService service_; // a member variable

auto req = std::make_shared<Request>(); // Request is a struct with context and stream members
service_.RequestCall(&req->getContext(), &req->getStream(), cqueue_.get(), cqueue_.get(), tag); // the program is giving seg fault at this line
```

**Attempt:**

I eliminated the possibility that a buggy service to be proxied is causing this.

I am wondering how to proceed debugging after that. As the `RequestCall()` is inside GRPC, so I want to ask what would be the next step of getting closer to the bug.

**Update:**

The stacktrace is aligned with the observed crash. As you can see in the frame-1 it is calling the RequestCall(). Below the frame 1, it is program internal functions.

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff37c61c6 in grpc::ServerInterface::GenericAsyncRequest::GenericAsyncRequest(grpc::ServerInterface*, grpc::GenericServerContext*, grpc::internal::ServerAsyncStreamingInterface*, grpc_impl::CompletionQueue*, grpc_impl::ServerCompletionQueue*, void*, bool) () from /opt/third/grpc/1.28.1/lib/libgrpc++.so.1
#1  0x00007ffff37b58c5 in grpc::AsyncGenericService::RequestCall(grpc::GenericServerContext*, grpc_impl::ServerAsyncReaderWriter<grpc::ByteBuffer, grpc::ByteBuffer>*, grpc_impl::CompletionQueue*, grpc_impl::ServerCompletionQueue*, void*) ()
   from /opt/third/grpc/1.28.1/lib/libgrpc++.so.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Having a callstack for the crash would be helpful to see what's going wrong.

Comment: Good point. updated now